# Use INSERT INTO with multiple SELECT statements

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to insert several rows into a table.  Almost all of the values for these rows match up with another set of records on the same table, so I am curious if I can write a single INSERT statement with multiple SELECT statements to insert multiple rows.  Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, col4)

SELECT (newRecordID, col2, col3, col4)
FROM table WHERE col1 = oldRecordID AND col4 = 0
SELECT (newRecordID, col2, col3, col4)
FROM table WHERE col1 = oldRecordID AND col4 = 1
SELECT (newRecordID, col2, col3, col4)
FROM table WHERE col1 = oldRecordID AND col4 = 2
SELECT (newRecordID, col2, col3, col4)
FROM table WHERE col1 = oldRecordID AND col4 = 3
```

Is this possible?  At the end, it should have inserted 4 rows, all with the same NewRecordID, with col4 values 0-3, and the other col values taken from the corresponding OldRecordID on the same table. When I run it, it just runs the first INSERT SELECT statement and then runs the others as their own SELECT statements.  Am I missing something in connecting these?  I could always just run it multiple times and change the value each time, but I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid that.  I appreciate and help or useful tips.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You could connect with Union which joins them into one recordset:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, col4)

SELECT (newRecordID, col2, col3, col4)
FROM table WHERE col1 = oldRecordID AND col4 = 0
union
SELECT (newRecordID, col2, col3, col4)
FROM table WHERE col1 = oldRecordID AND col4 = 1
union
SELECT (newRecordID, col2, col3, col4)
FROM table WHERE col1 = oldRecordID AND col4 = 2
union
SELECT (newRecordID, col2, col3, col4)
FROM table WHERE col1 = oldRecordID AND col4 = 3
```

Comment: No, this will not necessarily do the same thing - this will eliminate duplicates. Suggest `UNION ALL` unless you *know* you want duplicates eliminated.

Comment: Thanks!  This worked, and I used the UNION ALL statement as AB suggested.  I ultimately went with the solution from Ricardo C, but this was great as well.  I appreciate the quick response!

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, col4)

SELECT (newRecordID, col2, col3, col4)
FROM table WHERE col1 = oldRecordID AND col4 IN(0,1,2,3)
```

Comment: Awesome!  This worked.  I ended up using the UNION ALL solution, since I already had a bunch of SELECT statements written up.  Then I deleted the new entries and tried it this way too.  Will probably stick with this solution, as it saves a little more space.  Thanks!

Comment: @jlarson497 Glad to help. Either you chose mine or the one from Dr Aaron, just dont forget to accept one as the answer ;)